# Post Method using Flask

Tags: python, flask

Basically I'm working on an API that receives a POST method and then uses some data to create a json and send it.

There are some constraints, for example the names that I have in my database are different of the names that need to be in the json, but the values need to be the same. So what I did was create a dictionary and associate the names in the database with the names that will be in the json.

Code Explanation:

I receive a post method with a body message that will be useful to verify if that value exists in my database. If exists I will do another query that will retrieve all the devices that belong to the value that I received in the body. And then I do another query using influxDB to get all the values in the db.

In the first part what I do is for each device that I have I check if the ID exists in the influxDB and if it does I store the value.

With that value stored I check if my device name have a correspondent (a name that I don't have in the database in the) and I round the value received before and I append to a response.

In the second part I just check what names I have in my response and then put the values that are in the dictionary but not in the response there with a value of 0 (because that are names/values that I don't have in the database but are needed in the json response).

Code:

```
json_data = {
            "wid":None,
            "time_loc":None,
            "date_loc":None,
            "time_utc":None,
            "temp_out": "outTemp",
            "temp_in": "inTemp",
            "hum_out": "outHumidity",
            "hum_in": "inHumidity",
            "barometer": "barometer",
            "altimeter": "altimeter",
            "raw_bar":None,
            "bar_trend":None,
            "wind_spd": "windSpeed",
            "wind_dir": "windDir",
            "wind_avg_2min":None,
            "wind_avg_10min":None,
            "wind_gust_10min":None,
            "wind_gust_dir": "windGustDir",
            "dew_point": "dewpoint",
            "dew_point_cal":None,
            "wind_chill": "windchill",
            "heat_index": "heatindex",
            "thsw_index":None,
            "uv": "UV",
            "solar_radiation":None,
            "rain_rate": "rainRate",
            "storm_rain":None,
            "rain_15min":None,
            "rain_1h":None,
            "rain_day":None,
            "rain_daily":None,
            "rain_24":None,
            "rain_month":None,
            "rain_year":None,
            "et_day": "ET" ,
            "et_month":None,
            "et_year":None,
            "temp_extra_0": "extraTemp1",
            "temp_extra_1": "extraTemp2",
            "temp_extra_2": "extraTemp3",
            "temp_extra_3": "extraTemp4",
            "temp_extra_4": "extraTemp5",
            "temp_extra_5": "extraTemp6",
            "temp_extra_6": None,
            "temp_leaf_0":"leafTemp1",
            "temp_leaf_1": "leafTemp2",
            "temp_leaf_2": None,
            "temp_leaf_3":None,
            "temp_soil_0": "soilTemp1",
            "temp_soil_1": "soilTemp2",
            "temp_soil_2": "soilTemp3",
            "temp_soil_3": "soilTemp4",
            "hum_extra_0": "extraHumid1",
            "hum_extra_1": "extraHumid2",
            "hum_extra_2": "extraHumid3",
            "hum_extra_3": "extraHumid4",
            "hum_extra_4": "extraHumid5",
            "hum_extra_5": "extraHumid6",
            "hum_extra_6": "extraHumid7",
            "soil_moist_0": "soilMoist1",
            "soil_moist_1": "soilMoist2",
            "soil_moist_2": "soilMoist3",
            "soil_moist_3": "soilMoist4",
            "wet_leaf_0": "leafWet1",
            "wet_leaf_1": "leafWet2",
            "wet_leaf_2":None,
            "wet_leaf_3":None,
            "console_batt":None,
            "stations_batt_status":None,
            "forecast_icon":None,
            "forecast_rule":None,
            "sunrise_loc_time":None,
            "sunset_loc_time":None,
    }     

@app.route("/info/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def get_current_data_devices():
    isAuth = False
    
    auth = request.authorization
    if auth and auth.username == ApiFlask.post_auth["username"] and auth.password == ApiFlask.post_auth["password"]:
        isAuth = True
    else:
        isAuth = False
        return "Unauthorized", 401

    if isAuth:
        data = request.get_data(as_text=True)
        data = json.loads(data)
        
        g_id = data["gateway_id"]
        print(f"gateway_id: {g_id}")                
            
        valid_gateway = ApiFlask.getValidGateway(g_id)
        if(valid_gateway):

                devices = ApiFlask.getDataFromDevices(g_id)
                influx_results = influxDB.get_all_devices()
                response = []
                             
                # FIRST PART      
                for device in devices:
                    influx_value = 0
                    for key in influx_results:
                        #print(key)
                        if str(device["d_id"]) == str(key):
                            influx_value = influx_results[key]  
                            print(influx_results[key])
                            break                             
    
                    for key, val in ApiFlask.json_data.items():
                        if str(device["d_piv_slug"]) == str(val):
                            try:
                                aux_value = round(influx_value, 2)
                                #print(influx_value)
                            except:
                                aux_value = 0 
                            if str(device["d_piv_slug"]) == None: 
                                break                                       
                            response.append({key: aux_value})
                            break

                # SECOND PART    
                not_in_database = []
                for key in ApiFlask.json_data:
                    if key not in [list(item.keys())[0] for item in response]:
                        not_in_database.append({key:0})

                for item in not_in_database:
                    for key in item:
                        if response: # se a lista tiver conteudo, tem keys
                            if key not in response[0].keys():
                                response.append({key:item[key]})
                        else:
                            response.append({key:item[key]})
                
                response.sort(key=lambda x: list(ApiFlask.json_data).index(list(x.keys())[0]))
                return json.dumps(response, indent=4), 200
        else:
            return 'Bad Request' , 400
```

I'm wondering if this code is good, if is not very pratical... I would like to hear your opinions.

Answer (score 2):

```
json_data = {
            "wid": ...
```

The datastructure is nice enough.
But the identifier name is just terrible, it tells me very little.
Call it something like `db_to_json_name`
(if I've managed to read the code properly,
still unsure of that).

---

```
def get_current_data_devices():
    isAuth = False
```

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you spell it `is_auth`.
Consider being more verbose: `is_authorized`.
Then there's no confusion with the notion of "is authenticated".

---

This function is, ummm, a trifle long.
I'm not saying it's *too* long, necessarily.
But it's getting there.
Be on the lookout for helpers you can extract from it.

```
    if isAuth:
```

Consider bailing early with

```
    if not isAuth:
            return 'Bad Request' , 400
```

The advantage is that the rest of the function body
will be four spaces closer to left margin.

---

```
        print(f"gateway_id: {g_id}")
```

Consider using a
[logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) here.
If nothing else, you get timestamps for free.

```
        if(valid_gateway):
```

Lose the extraneous `(` `)` parens -- this isn't C code.

And again, you can bail early (`if not valid_gateway:`).
That would save yet another indent level.
Or you could extract the remainder as a helper function,
which again would reset the indent level
and would expose a test candidate for your
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).

---

```
                # FIRST PART      
                ...
                # SECOND PART
```

zomg, you're killing me!
If "first" / "second" are references to external documentation,
then include the docs with the CodeReview submission.
Otherwise, I'm left asking, "What were you trying to tell me?"

My typical advice would be to break out a pair of
helper functions. But usually we have a comment
like `# reticulate the splines` so we know the helper
should be named `def reticulate_splines():`.
Here, I am utterly at a loss, you have supplied zero hints
to the Gentle Reader.

```
                            except:
                                aux_value = 0
```

No.

You seem to be coping with `round(None)` here.
Never use a bare `except`, so as not to interfere with
KeyboardInterrupt CTRL/C handling.

Prefer `except TypeError:`, if that was your intent.
Or minimally catch `except Exception:`,
as `flake8` was doubtless trying to tell you when you linted.

It looks like you could sensibly extract a pair of tiny
helpers just in the "first part" alone.
Naming them would offer some documentation value.

---

In the "second part", you might find that
[set difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference)
is more convenient than looping.

Consider renaming `not_in_database` to `missing_from_database`.
Why? Humans do better with identifiers that are stated in
the positive rather than the negative.
It's just easier to reason about the code's behavior that way.

```
                        if response: 
                            if key not in response[0].keys():
                                response.append({key:item[key]})
                        else:
                            response.append({key:item[key]})
```

We have a pair of tests and a pair of assignments here, which seems like
[more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
code than necessary.
Could testing "this AND that" give us code with just a single assignment?

```
                response.sort(key=lambda x: list(ApiFlask.json_data).index(list(x.keys())[0]))
```

This is just too much code for an anonymous one-liner.
`def` it as a named function, please.

---

Up top you told me a pair of web verbs were valid
for this function: `methods=["POST", "GET"]`

I am still waiting for the punchline.
Does the behavior differ between those verbs?
Do we have any automated
[unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
to verify this function's behavior,
or the behavior of its helpers?
I didn't notice anything that was POST-specific.

The various DB functions seemed to read / get data.
If they have side effects on tables,
be sure to call that out,
and consider choosing a function name which clarifies that.

---

This code achieves some of its design goals.

There is probably some review context missing from
this submission. As written, without additional context,
I would be unwilling to delegate maintenance tasks on
this codebase and would be reluctant to accept such tasks,
since some technical debt would need to be paid down
prior to adding new features.
There is an opportunity to improve this code
prior to merging it down to `main`.

Comment: `The datastructure is nice enough. But the identifier name is just terrible, it tells me very little. Call it something like db_to_json_name (if I've managed to read the code properly, still unsure of that).` 
You read it right, that json is just to help me to see if I have the values in the database, and then get the keys associated.

Comment: `zomg, you're killing me! If "first" / "second" are references to external documentation, then include the docs with the CodeReview submission. Otherwise, I'm left asking, "What were you trying to tell me?"` What I mean with "# first part" and "#second part" was just to separate the code that was below that tags. Like, below "#first part" is where I append only the values that I have in the database and the "#second part" is where I append the values that I don't have in the database.

Comment: About the rest, I will try to apply what you said, changing some names, remove the useless () in the if statements and use the if not instead. Thank you for your review, I really appreciate it, helps me to improve. If there is something more that you see that I need to change, please let me know!

Comment: If I could leave you with one thought to summarize any code review or self-review, it is from [SICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs): "_Programs should be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute._" Ensuring some random reviewer who lacks context will easily understand your code is important. But your most important Reader is yourself, some months later, after current context is long lost and you have to pick it up again by consulting the text. So be kind to the Gentle Reader -- you're doing _yourself_ a favor!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **authentication**: I would expect to see the logic implemented *outside* of your route, by using a **decorator** to protect the views (routes) that require authentication.

Since you're using Apiflask, then as per their [documentation](https://apiflask.com/usage/#use-appauth_required-to-protect-your-views) you would need something like:

```
@app.auth_required(auth)
```

and add some authentication code as required.

The fact that you have only one route at present does not change the fact that it's better to externalize this stuff: your function should do only one thing, and do it well.
Your approach is bug-prone, since you are setting the `isAuth` variable at multiple places.

To reiterate what's been said before, don't swallow exceptions. Especially when you're catching all of them. Instead be specific about what kind of exception you expect to happen. Use a logger, and log them. This will help with debugging later. And if all you want is to have provide `aux_value` with a fallback value of 0, then it looks like a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is appropriate.